# SQL Server 2012 Merge Replication - Full Text Indexes

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I have an issue setting up merge replication on a SQL 2012 instance.

The push of the snapshot to the subscriber is failing and the reason I discovered was because there is a SP that uses a Full Text Index that has not been generated on a table.

A lot of searching about revealed that there is a property that is false by default that defines if a full text index should be copied.

[image: Copy Full text indexes]

I thought I had found the solution, set this property to true and triggered a new snapshot, however, the same issue was still encountered and when I went back to check the property the copy full text index property was set to false again??

I have tried a few times in the hope it was just me forgetting to save or something, from what I can see, the property stays at true until the snapshot is rerun, after that the property is back at false again, I am wondering if I have come up against a bug in SQL server, however, a google does not appear to indicate this is true.

I have tried deleting and recreating the publication. I have also tried disabling the distributor and publisher in order to force a fresh distribution DB to be created, thinking that maybe there is a corruption somewhere.

Both servers are running SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012R2

Does anyone have any fresh ideas?

Comment: There is **no** SQL Server **2012 R2** version - just **2012** - corrected

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with full text catalogs/search setup when using old SQL Server 2012 SSMS version. IDE has many full-text setup related issues(bugs were reported to MS). And only way to achieve proper functionality was to use t-sql commands only. After SSMS became separate from SQL Server product, these IDE bugs were fixed. No problems when working with full-text and SSMS IDE anymore. My SSMS version is 17.8.1, server version 2012 - 11.0.5343.0 (X64)(Build 7601: Service Pack 1).

Maybe your problems is related with IDE bugs too? Try to upgrade SSMS version (if you have older), ant then check situation again.

**Update:**
Here is related topic with full-text & merge replication problem. Hope this helps:
[link1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb285cb5-4dd6-4617-acc5-63878c075201/full-text-index-and-merge-replication?forum=sqlreplication)

Comment: I tried upgrading my SSMS instance to 17.8.1 but to no avail. I have tried creating the aticle using t-sql also which does not seam to have any effect. I can see using sql profiler that the main catalog is being created on the subscriber, however, the table does not have the index applied to it?

Comment: What do you mean "I tried upgrading my SSMS instance to 17.8.1 but to no avail."? You unable to install freeware SSMS 17.7.1?

Comment: Oh sorry, that was not the best explination. I meant that I have upgraded SMSS to 17.8.1 but the issue around setting the Copy Full Text property still remains.

Comment: Sorry, dont have any ideas anymore. I updated my original answer with link to post with very similar full text and replication problem. Please check it, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I eventually ran out of ideas and logged a call with Microsoft. Turns out that this is a bug and it effects all SQL server versions from SQL 2012 right through to SQL server 2017 from what I am being told.

Microsoft have said they are working on a patch for this but in the meantime I am having to manually script Full Text resources until something comes through.

Hope this helps anyone that comes across this issue.